# Writing better JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to see how I can write plain javascript that would do the same thing that I can do in jquery.

I wrote this for hide/show sub navigation:

```
var i = 0;
var header = document.querySelector( 'header' ).childNodes;
for( i; i<=header.length-1; i++ ){
    if( header[i].tagName !== undefined ){
        var nav = header[i].childNodes;
        for( i=0; i<=nav.length-1; i++ ){
            if( nav[i].tagName !== undefined ){
                if( nav[i].tagName === "MENU" ){
                    nav[i].className = "hide";
                } else {
                    nav[i].onclick = function(){
                        var dest = this.attributes.href.nodeValue;
                        for( i=0; i<=nav.length-1; i++ ){
                            if( nav[i].className === "show" )
                            nav[i].className = "hide";  
                        }
                        document.getElementById( dest.replace( "#", "" ) ).className = "show";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

html is:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#work">Work</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <menu id="home">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Mission</a>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </menu>
            <menu id="work">
                <a href="#">Web</a>
                <a href="#">Print</a>
                <a href="#">Media</a>
            </menu>
            <menu id="contact">
                <a href="#">Info</a>
                <a href="#">Sales</a>
                <a href="#">Support</a>
            </menu>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

with some css to display:none or display:block for .hide/.show

My question would be "is there a better way?"

Also, when I try to move the function outside of .onclick, I can't use "this" as variable.

```
nav[i].onclick = showHide( nav );
function showHide( el ){
   var dest = this.attributes.href.nodeValue;
     for( i=0; i<=el.length-1; i++ ){
     if( el[i].className === "show" )
       el[i].className = "hide";  
     }
     document.getElementById( dest.replace( "#", "" ) ).className = "show";
}
```

How can I pass the variable of the element being clicked on as "this"?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use jQuery? It seems a bit silly to not use jQuery even if it would simply and cleanly accomplish what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Again, I'm trying to understand plain javascript.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? It's a little hard to follow your code.  Maybe setup a JSFiddle too?

Comment: try to read about event delegation, for ex. http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: @nanpx - everything works, I wanted to see if there were any place in the code that could be tightened up (for learning purposes.)

Comment: @Igor - thanks! eventBubbling is exactly the type of things that I need to be more aware of.

Comment: I think that rewording the title will solve the issue with this question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use querySelector like this, then iterate through those elements instead of doing many loops

```
var menu_s = document.querySelector('header > nav > menu');

var a_s = document.querySelector('header > nav > a'); //as is a key word
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something related with JavaScript or JQuery is more about coding style which will make your code look good and pro.

Try to encapsulate actions like adding a class or removing a class and put also comments:

```
/**
* Adds a class to the given object
* @param object 
* @param className
**/ 
var addClass = function(object, className){
    //Validate if object exists 
    if(object){
        //Validate if is a html object
        if(object.parentNode){
            object.className += " " + className;
        }
    }
};
```